# Creating MP3 playlist

Tags: plugin-development

I have a website which I am looking to redesign and I have had WordPress recommended to me.
My website makes available many hundreds of albums for the listener to select and listen to as if it was a CD player selecting whichever track they like on the screen. Each album has its own webpage and playlist.
Before I start the process of learning how to use WordPress could you tell me if it is possible to replicate this type of "CD Player" playlist in WordPress? I would also like to be able to customise the appearance of the "CD Player" interface as well. Could you please let me know if I am able to acheive all of this in WordPress and if so point me in the right direction of where to find specific information on a MP3 player which will suit my requirements.
Here is an example of just one album within my website to take a look at:-
http://www.regalzonophone.com/Player%20Canadian%20-%20FGSCD1196%20-%201997%20Christmas%20Festival.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the correct plugin. [Audio Album](https://wordpress.org/plugins/audio-album/) is just one such plugin. Try searching the plugin repository using a variety of different queries, and you'll probably find what you are looking for. Here's a search on "[mp3 album](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=mp3%20album)".

As for customising the appearance of the player interface, this depends, in part, on what kind of player the plugin is using. But just about everything can be styled in WordPress using a child theme. Because everybody wants to make a lot of changes in WordPress, I usually recommend setting up a child theme fairly early on.